# Is it possible to implement date field as one select list?

Tags: datetime

Currently when we use default date field with widget select list, it shows like 3 drop-downs with Year, month and date. Is there any way to make it as one drop down. I need to display few dates from today's date( may be 5 or 10 dates).

My date field should look like below section. Format can be different but will display whole date in one select list.

```
September 19 2014
September 20 2014
September 21 2014
```

Comment: Why? Scrolling to 2010 would be hell, and 30 days x 12 months x 10 years means 3600 positions. A little hell for your user's browser. Each date is about 16 bytes, so we are talking about 56 KB data for one field. With `<option>` tags markup and all that, make it about **128 KB**. Really? Category listing of a page I currently work on has 35,5 KB of syntax. And it is a pretty complicated one, with filters etc.

Comment: I mean, if you only need few dates from now, it's still risky. Forget a limit somewhere, and your site have a problem. Disabling year and month would be safer, if less convenient. I'm not saying you not to do this, I just wanted to make sure you know what you are risking by doing it.

Comment: @Mołot I think the case is valid enough look at the scenario of booking tickets where you have 3-5 days date or any e-paper website where you can read last 5-10 days newspaper as well. Selecting three fields for a user will be cumbersome and the user want to remove that complexity I think. Applying limit somewhere in PHP code will not put user at risk anyhow.

Comment: @AshishBairagi I actually want the similar scenario of having   3-10 days. So selecting the date from 3 drop downs is not that much user friendly. Thats why I am trying to get in in a single selection list.

Comment: Where will the valid date values be stored? I think I could formulate a solution for you given that information.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend replacing the date field with text box and add a date pop to allow certain dates. This could be easily done by `hook_form_alter` in your custom module. See below:

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_form_alter().
     */
    function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
      switch($form_id) {
        case 'your_form_id':
          $form['yourfield']['#type'] = 'date_popup';
          $form['yourfield']['#date_format'] = 'd/m/Y';
          $form['yourfield']['#datepicker_options'] = array('minDate' => '-15D', 'maxDate' => '-1D');
          $form['yourfield']['#readonly'] = TRUE;
          break;
      }
    }
```

You will need the [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date)  module enabled before you can use this.
Let me know how you go..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I have seen this method before, but my requirement is to display it as select list instead of calender. Is there any way to do it.

Comment: Are you looking to make 3 select lists; ie day, month,year.  If its just one select list wouldn't that be a bit mental !